# SEO link for dynamic database data

Tags: php, dynamic-url

I have problem with SEO links. The Issue is that i would like to open an Clean SEO link to reach any article in my database, while simultaneously naming it in this format:

```
website.com/category/id/title
```

The problem is, that the data in question is also being fetched from a database, so its all dynamic.

This is the "a" tag that pushes sends me to my web page by the name article.

```
<p class="readmore">
 <a href="article?category=<?php echo $ArtCat; ?>&artid=<?php echo $ArtID; ?>&title=<?php echo $dashedTitle; ?>">Read More</a>
</p>
```

I would like for it to be like this, but when i change it to that, it doesnt move on to the next page as expected because the variables aren't defined.

```
<a href="article/<?php echo $ArtCat; ?>/<?php echo $ArtID; ?>/<?php echo $dashedTitle; ?>">Read More</a>
```

This is whats on article.php

```
<?php
    echo "Article Category: " . $_GET['category'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Article ID: " . $_GET['artid'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Article Title: " . $_GET['title'];
    echo "<br>";
?>
```

my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ article.php?category=$1&artid=$2&title=$3
```

Comment: A little Tip: If your server is configurated properly the shortcut for `<?php echo $variable;?>` is `<?=$variable?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start in your .htaccess the RewriteEngine, otherwise the RewriteRule won't work.

`RewriteEngine on`

This code needs to stand before your RewriteRule.

Comment: Oh its on. I didn't include it in the code above by accident!

Comment: @JohnMercel The rest is working for me, if I test your code.
You need to watch out, that you set your variables properly, like the other answer and that you dont overwrite your htaccess rules. That could end in a 500.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't missunderstand you in *"it doesnt move on to the next page as expected because the variables aren't defined."*, the variables `$ArtCat`, `$ArtID` and `$dashedTitle` are not defined in:

```
<a href="article/<?php echo $ArtCat; ?>/<?php echo $ArtID; ?>/<?php echo $dashedTitle; ?>">Read More</a>
```

You are trying to access `index.php` which contains the `<a>` code to redirect user to `article.php`, am I right? The variables must be defined in the `index.php` or include into it. Maybe you have some code in `index.php`:

```
<?php
// include some files
// query some database
// some code
?>
<a href="article/<?php echo $ArtCat; ?>/<?php echo $ArtID; ?>/<?php echo $dashedTitle; ?>">Read More</a>
```

Not defined vars means you don't have `$ArtCat = "article-category-name"` and none of other vars you request in `<a href>`

If the code contains such attribution "`=`":

0. Check for typos;
1. If happens in `// include some files` (the code belongs to another file but it is included), make sure included are being well included; try `require` instead, log/echo the vars to be sure;
2. If happens in `// query some database`, try some logs (or `var_dumps`) to check if databases results are not coming null values;

If the attribution happens `// some code` check if the variables are not being defined inside functions.

```
<?php
function something ()
{
    $ArtCat = "article-category-name";
    ...
}
something();
echo $ArtCat; // Here $ArtCat it's not defined
 
function somethingElse ()
{
    $ArtCat = "article-category-name";
    ... // the other vars
    return [ $ArtCat, /* the other vars */ ];
}
somethingElse();
echo $ArtCat; // Here $ArtCat it's not defined
```

If the values of vars come from $_REQUEST, make sure they're not coming null.
If the values of vars come from environment vars, try echoing before and check if php runs in same scope they are defined.

Maybe some more details can help me to help you.